# Continious RS485 communication and UI in C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have RS485 slave devices connected to a computer. Computer ask a device some question and  waits on response.

The communication should be continious with user interface to show data from devices and to control them in real time.

I have developed some applications with RS485 communication with use of bacgroundWorker.

I'm not sure but I think this is not the proper way to use it this time, becouse user interface elements can not be changed or updated from backgroundWorker.

I could probably use backgroundWorker and global data variables, and then update UI on timer event. But I have concerns about this solution.
thanks!

Comment: Can you show the codes ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a background worker, as Serial Ports support asynchronous operations - you subscribe to `DataReceived` and after opening the port, your event will be called periodically with received data.

You then need to buffer the data until you build up a complete message packet (you may get data in dribs and drabs, there is no guarantee that you will get fully formed packets), and then update your UI (usually using a BeginInvoke to pass control back to your UI thread)

Comment: BeginRead? In which version? I don't have a BeginRead method in .NET4.5.

Comment: Sorry - a memory glitch! You don't need to initiate a read, you just subscribe to the DataRecieved event and Open the port and you'll be called back whenever data is ready. (BeginRead is used on other async operations, such as on streams. I've edited my answer to correct this mistake)

Comment: Your glitched remembered SerialPort.BaseStream.BeginRead().

Answer (score -1):

I designed the system of remote monitoring and control which works with controllers by RS-485. It implemented as Windows Service which writes data in SQL Server. UI Application (It is Web Application in my last version) takes the data from SQL. In previous versions I used Named Pipes.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: I advised to use Windows Service as a way. What is wrong with it? It's not good to mix server and client

Comment: I am guessing here but I think the OP is just writing a simple tool for monitoring the communication. I dont think adding a Windows service will be justifiable in his scenario. Plus, everything need not be based on a server client architecture.